# Multilingual Search using language Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nlp, lucene

i am working on a project to perform multilingual full-text search using Elasticsearch. The historical training dataset i am using is also multilingual and i am trying now to configure text analysis with language analyzer and language detection.

1) i am using the following link as a guide and as it is written in the first paragraph i need to install **an Inference Ingest Processor**. How can i install it? (i am not familiar with Java and new in elasticsearch)
https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/multilingual-search-using-language-identification-in-elasticsearch

2) Elasticsearch offers language Analyzer for many languages i will need to configure Analyzers in 8 languages if i follow this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html  i will have to create 8 different custom analyzers which is quite long. Is there any shorter way to write one setting for 8 languages?

Answer (score 1):

First as mentioned in the blog `an Inference Ingest Processor` is a Machine learning(ML) feature and unless you have a use case you don't need it, also it's part of X-pack and not the core Elasticsearch so you might have to enable X-pack module and buy if it's not included in the basic tier of X-pack.

Coming to your second question, As mentioned in the blog two approaches one is having a separate index for each language that way you don't have to define all the language-specific field and, Second way which we use is the one field for each language and all the languages will the part of the same index.

There is no overhead of maintaining 8 custom analyzers as most of the analyzer are inbuilt, you can check [Elasticsearch language analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html) which all are supported in your use case. And others, if you have to create it, will be just one-time effort and would be part of your setting and mapping.

Below is one example index mapping of per field approach where I am using the inbuilt analyzer of most common languages.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "en": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "russian": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "russian"
            },
            "spanish": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "spanish"
            },
            "swedish": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "swedish"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: about  `Inference Ingest Processor` i was thinking, detecting the language can help the search engine provide good results even with unknown languages or am i getting the concept wrong? I have all languages indexed in the same field in a document and users do not  need to select  the language before searching.  In this case i can use your second way  suggestion "the one field for each language"?  (as i am new in ES: what i mean by field is the "column" with the raws where all my multilingual historical full-text-search are listed. many thanks :)

Comment: in this case i can reach my goal without using language detection with `inference Ingest processor`? Using language Analyzers shall provides a  good performance?

Comment: @yolo25 yeah def it this feature is just released and still under development and even mentioned in official site its experimental feature while language analyzers have been there since long time and thousand of systems are using them and very scalable and provides a good performance :) I handle billion of docs using language analyzers :)

Comment: i need multiple language analyzers for one field. I cant use the mapping/solution u suggested above :)

Comment: @yolo25 even with multi-filed https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html  which is again using different fields to store the data its not possible, what you just mentioned I am afraid not possible :)

Comment: i have all descriptions in one column in the datasystem and they are in TBs and growing continiously. How can can i make from one column multi language fields to be able to apply the per field approach. Is that even possible? thanks :)

Comment: @yolo25, as mentioned earlier applying multiple analyzers on a single field, is not possible also it would be great if you follow up on your second question which you asked yesterday and I gave my answer there as well :)

Comment: @yolo25 did you get a chance to look at my last comments? let me know if you need more info